# How to get the file value using ng2-file-upload using angular on button click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here i am creating a file upload using ng2-file-upload where i am dropping file and usually i am getting value of that till now it is fine now my issue is even thought i placed drop function but after dropping file i also want to retrieve the file upload value using a button click function how can i achieve this below is my code

Note: here i need to get the  fileList value

currently im getting file list values using filedropped method but along with that by using the button click i need to get the value

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload';


const URL = 'https://evening-anchorage-3159.herokuapp.com/api/';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  fileSelectState = {};
  formVisible = true;
  temp: any;

  public showInputForm: boolean = true;
  public selectAll: boolean = true;
  selectedAll: any;


  imga = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/soft-scraps/256/Button-Upload-icon.png";

  public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL});
  public hasBaseDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
  public hasAnotherDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
  public selectedFilesArray = [];
  private selectedFile;



    public selectFile(e: any): void {
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement || e.currentTarget;
    var value = target.innerHTML;
    this.selectedFile = value;
    this.selectAll = true;
    this.selectedFilesArray = [];
    this.selectedFilesArray.push(this.selectedFile);

  }
  public fileOverBase(e: any): void {
    this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
  }

    public selectAllFiles(e: any): void {

    this.selectedFilesArray = [];
    if (e.target.checked) {

      this.selectAll = true;

      for (var item in this.uploader.queue) {
        this.selectedFilesArray.push(this.uploader.queue[item].file.name);
      }
    }

    for (var item in this.uploader.queue) {
      this.fileSelectState[this.uploader.queue[item].file.name] = e.target.checked
    }


  }
 public fileDropped(fileList: any): void
  {
    for(var i =0 ; i< fileList.length; i++){
        this.fileSelectState[fileList[i].name] = true;
    }

  }

   public fileChecked(e: any): void {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      console.log(this.selectedFilesArray);
      this.selectedFilesArray.push(e.target.value);
      if (this.selectedFilesArray.length > 1) {

        this.selectedFile = e.target.value;


      }
      else {

        this.selectedFile = e.target.value;


      }

    }
    if (!e.target.checked) {

      var index = this.selectedFilesArray.indexOf(e.target.value, 0);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.selectedFilesArray.splice(index, 1);
        if (this.selectedFilesArray.length > 1) {


          this.selectedFile = this.selectedFilesArray[0];


        }
        else if (this.selectedFilesArray.length == 1) {

          this.selectAll = false;
          this.selectedFile = this.selectedFilesArray[0];


        }
        else if (this.selectedFilesArray.length == 0) {

          this.selectedFile = '';


        }
      }

    }



  }

  getInfo(){
    console.log('file info');
  }

}
```

url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s6g1v6

[image: like first log the file list has to be displayed]

Comment: What content do you need after the button click

Comment: file List i am alerady getting that using fileDrop method but along with that i want the same using  button click also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: OP wants File objects available within the scope of the component. Code modified below.

Store the entire [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object rather than just its name property. First, change the Change the `fileSelectState` to and array (or use a different class member for this). Then Change `fileDropped()` method to this:

```
public fileDropped(fileList: any): void
  {
    for(var i =0 ; i< fileList.length; i++){
        this.fileSelectState.push(fileList[i]);
    }

  }
```

Note: if you don't have to support IE, you can replace the for loop with:

```
this.fileSelectState = Array.from(fileList);
```

Change:

```
getInfo(){
  console.log('file info');
}
```

To:

```
getInfo(){
  console.log(this.fileSelectState);
}
```

Wherever you need the file name then use this:

```
this.fileSelectState[0].name
```

Comment: yeah but here fileSelectState  wont work bcoz in the fileDrop method if u see there is fileList  here when ever a file is dropped it get the whole file details like filename,filesize etc  but where are as fileSelectState get only file name please check the updated question where i posted the image

Comment: That is why I put the disclaimer. In the beginning of the question. My recommendation then will be in and edit to my answer in a moment.

Comment: that will do but the variable previously which are there are used by some 1000 lines of applications  this.fileSelectState[fileList[i].name] = true; so based on that logic application depended on it any way thank you randy

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, forget to tell you to change ti to an array!! Good catch.

Comment: Edited to include changing to an array type.